# Reshape Numpy Array with keeping indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'll be honest, not sure that the title covers the complete topic.

I'm not a python programmer but we received a library that returns a 3D numpy array.

The values are temperatures in a wall. But sometimes some sensors are out of order or malfunctioning, this library build for us handles these problems. We provide the routine sets of data. The first one is a table with x,y coordinates and the inside temperature, the second one just the same x,y and outside temperatures.

The function returns a 3D numpy array.

The most outer array has a size of 3. with the indexs 0 = internal temperature, 1 = corrected internal temperature, 2 = outside temperature.

Inside we find a array that holds the x array of the y array values.

So getting lists out of that array works with (where insidetemp=0, outsidetemp=2)

```
insideTemperatureList = temperatureData[INSIDETEMP, 0,:]
outsideTemperatureList = temperatureData[OUTSIDETEMP, 0,:]
```

Final question .. I would like to get this in a array like this (° sign just to clarify)

[type-temp, x-coord, y-coord, temp]

[[0,0,0,15°],[0,0,1,16°],[0,0,2,90°] .... [1,0,2,16°] ... [2,10,10,-3°]]

Anybody could help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the test array, of shape 3 layers by (4, 4), I started with
individual "layers":

```
inside  = np.arange(41, 57, dtype=int).reshape(4,4)
corr    = np.arange(21, 37, dtype=int).reshape(4,4)
outside = np.arange( 1, 17, dtype=int).reshape(4,4)
# Layer indices
INSIDETEMP = 0; CORRTEMP = 1; OUTSIDETEMP = 2
```

and created *temperatureData* as:

```
temperatureData = np.stack([inside, corr, outside])
```

To print the "outside" layer alone, you can run:

```
temperatureData[OUTSIDETEMP]
```

And to get your expected result, run the following one-liner:

```
result = np.array([ idx + (x,) for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(temperatureData) ])
```

The initial part of the result (the whole *inside* layer and the first
row of *corrected* layer is:

```
array([[ 0,  0,  0, 41],
       [ 0,  0,  1, 42],
       [ 0,  0,  2, 43],
       [ 0,  0,  3, 44],
       [ 0,  1,  0, 45],
       [ 0,  1,  1, 46],
       [ 0,  1,  2, 47],
       [ 0,  1,  3, 48],
       [ 0,  2,  0, 49],
       [ 0,  2,  1, 50],
       [ 0,  2,  2, 51],
       [ 0,  2,  3, 52],
       [ 0,  3,  0, 53],
       [ 0,  3,  1, 54],
       [ 0,  3,  2, 55],
       [ 0,  3,  3, 56],
       [ 1,  0,  0, 21],
       [ 1,  0,  1, 22],
       [ 1,  0,  2, 23],
       [ 1,  0,  3, 24],
```

Comment: Much appreciated !!